# How to write above fractions - font issue

Tags: fonts, tex-core, mathematics

I'm trying to write a math document,and I have the following problem.
I wanted to create fractions like this:

[image: factions123161]

and the code that I used to create it is this:

```
   \documentclass[twoside,a4paper,leqno]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%% no empty pages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\cleardoublepage{%
\clearpage
\ifodd\value{page}\else\stepcounter{page}\fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{xltxtra}
%\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{extarrows}
%\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=cyan}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{pstricks-add}
%\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\input xymatrix.tex 

%\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black}

\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}






%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


usepackage{graphicx}


\makeatletter
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{tipa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{tipa}{m}{n}{<->tipa10}{}
\newcommand{\arc@char}{{\usefont{U}{tipa}{m}{n}\symbol{62}}}%

\newcommand{\arc}[1]{\mathpalette\arc@arc{#1}}

\newcommand{\arc@arc}[2]{%
   \sbox0{$\m@th#1#2$}%
   \vbox{
      \hbox{\resizebox{\wd0}{\height}{\rotatebox[origin=bottom]{180}{\arc@char}}}
       \nointerlineskip
       \box0
   }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\stackAboveArc}[2]{\begin{array}[b]{@{}c@{}}#1\\ \arc{#2}\end{array}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Document starts %%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\[
\dfrac{\stackAboveArc{x}{\hphantom{a}x\hphantom{a}}}{(x-2)(x+2)}-\dfrac{\stackAboveArc{x+2}{\hphantom{aa}1\hphantom{aa}}}{x(x+2)} \]



\end{document}
```

In my code there exists this code as well

```
% the next code replaces non-existent Olga Latin with GFSDidotItalic Latin
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1%
\newXeTeXintercharclass\GFSDidotoSubst%
\count255="0021%
\loop\ifnum\count255<"0341%
\XeTeXcharclass\count255=\GFSDidotoSubst%
\advance\count255 by 1%
\repeat%
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \GFSDidotoSubst = {\begingroup\GFSDidotoSubstFont}%
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \GFSDidotoSubst = {\begingroup\GFSDidotoSubstFont}%
\XeTeXinterchartoks \GFSDidotoSubst 0 = {\endgroup}%
\XeTeXinterchartoks \GFSDidotoSubst 4095 = {\endgroup}%
```

and when this is enabled the fractions are becoming to this

[image: problematic fractions]

when this code is disabled, wherever I have used the tasks environment the enumeration isn't visible as shown in the following picture:

[image: enumeration problem]

if there is anyone that can help, please help!
thank's.

Comment: why `\renewcommand\cleardoublepage{%` ???  why make the page number jump by two?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I thought that it used so I  won't have empty pages, but any way it's not the cause of the issue.